# What is the Quickest Way to Locate Captain Cryptic?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm working on the fragments for answering Captain Cryptic's quizzes in Academia 4XX AF. Is there an easier way to locate him than doing full circuits of the map?

For instance - could I just leave my character by a known spawning location and then repeatedly exit the zone and reload, or would I be wasting my time? If something like that is **confirmed** to work it could be faster (or at least lazier) to locate him.

I'm open to any other suggestions **other than running around searching for him**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official guide every time you reload Captain Cryptic appears in a random location. So in theory you could keep reloading at a known spawn spot although although seeing there are like 9 spawn spots this could be very time consuming.

npc's also give hints on captain cryptics location.
Anything that refers to the direction east means that cryptic is in grand avenue or in the alley. West means that captain cryptic is in new town

Comment: Confirmed - reloading the zone works. Quizzes 2 through 5 took me a total of 50 minutes using this method.

Comment: nice not as time consuming as i thought then